# Creating views for iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to create views that work for both for iPhone 5 and prior models. I have done my research and have found people suggesting the use of

```
setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

But I have the following questions regarding this.

1. If I am building in interface builder and plan on using the above line of code, do I leave the size option at "Retina 4 Full Screen"?
2. Will the above line of code account for images that were previously set at a specific location on 3.5 inch screens?
3. Is there a generic place I can put this line of code in my app so it does it for all views or do I need to put it in each viewController and within ViewDidLoad?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check your device hardware by using if condition and set your views according to device model

Comment: @Sudha Thanks for the reply but isn't this a huge hassle? and does this not defeat the purpose of that autoresize code? Thanks

Comment: We also faced that problem and autoresize code is not working......You can use CGRect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to deploy app only on iOS6, then you can  use autolayout option.

If you are targeting iOS 6.0 and previous version then you can use view resizing with autoresizingMask. One other approach you can use is that it can be to design separate views for iPhone 5 and iPhone 4S. Check screensize and load views accordingly, as in the case of universal apps.

Thanks,
Jim.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim. I plan on using only iOS 6+ (Should have made that clear above). Do you mind explaining the difference between UIViewAutoresizing and autoresizingMask? Can these be immediately applied through IB? Thanks - Alex

Comment: autoResizingMask is the property for view that is of type UIViewAutoresizing(typo error in my answer. corrected it).  @property(nonatomic) UIViewAutoresizing autoresizingMask. My suggestion is that if you are planning to use for iOS6+ then better you should go with AutoLayout option in the IB.

Comment: Thanks again Jim. Is there anything I need to set for the AutoLayout option in IB? Like I see things such as constraints but is simply setting the size option enough?

Comment: yes. Take a look at more details: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder